# WP Avada menu SEO

Tags: seo, menu

On my website I have two menus. This is because my Wordpress theme (Avada) only has one option; to use its so-called "standard menu".

Apparently this is not the best for Google. The 5 category image links which are below the main menu (Vins, Tour&Taste, Horses, Hideaway, Biofarming&Products) make up our prefered menu.

How can we show Google that this is the preferred menu? I think i can turn the Avada standard-menu off, but is there any tag or something to show to Google that this is a menu, and not just a link to other sites?

Comment: Where did you hear that multiple menus is not good for Google?   I've never heard anything like that.     Google doesn't care about menus, it cares about links.  It doesn't care whether links are in a menu or on the page.   Google doesn't pay attention to menus or have a "preferred" menu.

Comment: As per Stephen's comment above, where did you hear/see this information? I have been working in SEO for almost 10 years and have never heard such a thing and don't know how it would effect your SEO given that it is primarily based on quality, relevant links to your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the HTML Nav tag on your main menu. I'm not familiar with your theme but its likely you will need to edit your theme files.

https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/tag_nav.asp

Comment: The nav tag is used by browsers and screen readers, not search engines. OP has no means of signalling to search engines which links are his main navigation, nor does he need to.

Comment: I believe this to be incorrect although we can't confirm the inner workings of major search engine providers. Id be very surprised if the major players (Google/Bing) didn't see NAV tags as an indicator of the structure of your website. This would be an indicator which would aid them to identify your main pages and include extended listing in the search engine.

Comment: As Stephen Ostermiller mentioned, search engines don't care about menus, they care about links. Having lots of internal links to a page, whether they're within a <nav> element or not is what search engines use to work out the structure of the site.

Comment: We can neither prove or disprove what search engines use as ranking factors. I don't dispute they care about links but I believe it goes deeper than this. I have provided an example above of how I would expect a search engine to use the nav tags and irregardless of how search engines currently use HTML5 tags it not to say they will not change their algorithms. For this reason I would consider it best practice to include nav tags on your main menu.

Comment: @MatthewJasek Tanks! I will include them.

Answer (score 1):

> How can we show Google that this is the preferred menu?

My question to that question is "why".

Google is the middleman here. Your website should be designed primarily for your guests, not search engine robots. You need to format your menus so that guests are able to access them and that they fit the theme to your site. If your site turns out better for the guests from having two menus on the exact same page, then just do it. Only thing I suggest with menus is to not make two duplicate menus on the same page right next to each other.

Menu or links, Google will likely see it all as links anyway since in a menu, you'll have links to different sections of your site.